# loading List view images with multiple aync tasks

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, lazy-loading, android-volley

I have requirement to show images in list view, where, when the page loads, I will get file_name from  JSON list from network call, to form url form that filename. I need to perform another network call which downloads the file from s3 server to local server. I am using volley for imageloader how shall i achieve that here is the way i am doing

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Log.d(TAG, "getView called.. ");
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    AllMessage message = amList.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_peer_message, parent, false);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_am_name_top);
        holder.sub_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_am_name_bottom);
        holder.content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_am_content);
        holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_am_time);
        holder.img_icon = (NetworkImageViewRounded) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.img_clip = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_attachment_clip);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (message.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("group")) {

        holder.img_icon.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.group_icon);

        //holder.img_icon.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.group_icon);
        holder.name.setText(message.getGroupName());
        holder.name.setTag("group");
        holder.sub_name.setText(message.getName() != null ? message.getName() + ":" : "");
        holder.sub_name.setTag(message.getGroupID());
        holder.img_icon.setTag(message.getGroupAvatarUrl());
        if (message.getGroupAvatarUrl().equals("")) {
            //holder.img_icon.setImageUrl(null,imageLoader);
            holder.img_icon.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.group_icon);
            holder.img_icon.setImageUrl(null,imageLoader);
            holder.img_icon.setTag("");

        } else {
            if (message.getGroupAvatarUrl().contains("http")) {
                // holder.img_icon.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.group_icon);
                holder.img_icon.setTag(message.getGroupAvatarUrl());
                holder.img_icon.setImageUrl(message.getGroupAvatarUrl(),imageLoader);
                holder.img_icon.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.group_icon);

            } else {
                holder.img_icon.setTag(message.getGroupAvatarUrl());
                holder.img_icon.setImageUrl(FileUtil.getServerAttachmentPath() + "/" + message.getAvatarUrl(),
                            imageLoader);
                new DownLoadAttachmentsAsyncTask().execute(holder.img_icon);

                holder.img_icon.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.group_icon);


            }


        }

    } else {
        holder.img_icon.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.ic_doctor_default);
        holder.name.setText(message.getName());
        holder.name.setTag("individual");
        holder.sub_name.setText("");
        holder.sub_name.setTag(message.docID);
        holder.img_icon.setTag(message.getAvatarUrl());

        if (message.getAvatarUrl().equals("")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Empty Doc avathar for " + message.getName());
            holder.img_icon.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.ic_doctor_default);
            holder.img_icon.setImageUrl(null,imageLoader);
            //holder.img_icon.setImageUrl(null,imageLoader);

            //holder.img_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_doctor_default);
            //holder.img_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_doctor_default);
        } else {

            holder.img_icon.setImageUrl(FileUtil.getServerAttachmentPath() + "/" + message.getAvatarUrl(),
                        imageLoader);
            new DownLoadAttachmentsAsyncTask().execute(holder.img_icon);

            holder.img_icon.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.ic_doctor_default);
            //holder.img_icon.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.ic_doctor_default);
            //holder.img_icon.setImageUrl(FileUtil.getServerAttachmentPath() + "/" + message.getAvatarUrl(),imageLoader);

        }

    }



    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name, sub_name, content, time;
    NetworkImageViewRounded img_icon;
    ImageView img_clip;
}


 // DownLoad Async task for avathars 
public class DownLoadAttachmentsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<NetworkImageViewRounded, Void, NetworkImageViewRounded> {
    //private final WeakReference<NetworkImageViewRounded> imageViewReference;
    //private final WeakReference<Integer> position;

    public DownLoadAttachmentsAsyncTask() {
        //imageViewReference = new WeakReference<NetworkImageViewRounded>(imageViewReference);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected NetworkImageViewRounded doInBackground(NetworkImageViewRounded... params) {
        NetworkImageViewRounded  imageView = null;
        if (NetworkUtil.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
            imageView = params[0];
            // Log.d("doInBackground",fileName);
            if (APIEngine.downLoadAttachment(imageView.getTag().toString(), "avatar")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Downlaod done for name filename is "+imageView.getTag().toString());
                return imageView;

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Downlaod failed for   --- "+imageView.getTag().toString());
            }

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No network ");
        }
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(NetworkImageViewRounded imageView) {
        if (imageView != null) {

            if (imageView.getTag().toString() != null) {
                String fileUrl = imageView.getTag().toString();
                /*String fileNameJust;
                if(fileUrl.contains("http")){
                    fileNameJust = FileUtil.getFileNameFromS3URL(fileUrl);
                }else{
                    fileNameJust = fileUrl;
                }*/
                Log.d(TAG, FileUtil.getServerAttachmentPath() + "/" + fileUrl);
                imageView.setImageUrl(FileUtil.getServerAttachmentPath() + "/" + fileUrl,
                            imageLoader);

            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "Nul file URL");
            }
            //notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: simply...you have written your requirement here..?try it.?its not an issue?

Comment: I dont want to call downlaod API each time in getView() onscrolling scrolling ,downlaod file network call should call once per getView call

Comment: Use ViewHolder pattern for it...

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you go for lazy loading list view? http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134

Comment: I need to call another network call to form URL for each list row imageview

Answer (score 0):

No Need to use ImageLoader/Universal Imageloader Library. Checkout [This](http://square.github.io/picasso/) awesome library named Picasso. Download the jar file [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.4.0/picasso-2.4.0.jar). Include the jar in your project's Build path and it will load the images into your imageview using the Url by a simple method

```
    Picasso.with(context).load("imageurl.png").into(yourImageView);
```

Just use this line inside your getview method of the adapter.

Comment: I can achieve that using volley as well,i have additional network call for each list row to form url for image thats the problem

Comment: that's why I told you to use this library. it will handle all the calls automatically and caching also. and then you have not to worry about making calls to network every time getView() method is called